# UnicodeDecodeError when dumping to json input from console

Tags: python, json

I input some cyrillic text from console and when I try to dump it to json I get `exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte`. I can't figure out why because it doesn't happen always and text **is always** cyrillic.

Here's the part of the code where I input text:

```
item['title'] = raw_input('Title: ')
item['description'] = raw_input('Description: ')
```

And here's the line where I dump the dictionary to json:

```
line = json.dumps(dict(item), encoding='utf8') + "\n"
```

The item is not a dictionary, it's an object, so I need to convert it to dictionary first.
Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dmitry/.virtualenvs/test_scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 62, in _process_chain
    return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
  File "/home/dmitry/.virtualenvs/test_scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 65, in process_chain
    d.callback(input)
  File "/home/dmitry/.virtualenvs/test_scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 382, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/home/dmitry/.virtualenvs/test_scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/dmitry/.virtualenvs/test_scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/dmitry/Dropbox/coding/python/scrapy/videos_parser/videos_parser/pipelines.py", line 94, in process_item
    line = json.dumps(dict(item), encoding='utf8') + "\n"
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 233, in _encoder
    o = o.decode(_encoding)
  File "/home/dmitry/.virtualenvs/test_scrapy/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 15: invalid continuation byte
```

`sys.getdefaultencoding()` says I'm using `ascii`. I've tried to changed it to utf8 with `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` but it didn't work.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code I use to see how strings looked before decoding:

```
try:
    item['title'] = raw_input('Title: ')
    item['title'] = item['title'].decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print repr(item['title'])
try:
    item['description'] = raw_input('Description: ')
    item['description'] = item['description'].decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print repr(item['description'])
```

And here's what the output from console:

```
Title: На работе платят бабло, но работать надо на ней
'\xd0\x9d\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8f\xd1\x82 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe, \xd0\xbd\xd0\xd0\xbe \xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9'
Description: Я не против первого, но без второго мне веселей
'\xd0\xaf \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe \xd0, \xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7 \xd0\xb2\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbc\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9'
```

Comment: Please show us the *full* traceback. What encoding does the terminal use?

Comment: When you say that it doesn't happen always, do you mean that it only happens for certain inputs, or do you mean that for exactly the same input, it sometimes happens and sometimes doesn't? Have you found a way to reproduce it by opening a terminal, running your program and inputting a particular string? What terminal are you using? What does the `locale` command show? Can you reproduce the problem in something other than Python or in another terminal emulator?

Comment: Also, how are you entering this input? Are you copy-pasting or typing it out?

Comment: @Gilles the problem was not with python at all, I had some problems with terminal as Martijn figured out already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal appears to be botching UTF-8 input; *extra* `\dx0` bytes have been inserted:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> given = '\xd0\x9d\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8f\xd1\x82 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe, \xd0\xbd\xd0\xd0\xbe \xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9'
>>> expected = 'На работе платят бабло, но работать надо на ней' # requires UTF-8 terminal
>>> for opcode in difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=expected, b=given).get_opcodes():
...     print "%6s a[%d:%d] b[%d:%d]" % opcode
...     if opcode[0] == 'insert': print 'Inserted:', repr(given[opcode[3]:opcode[4]])
... 
 equal a[0:15] b[0:15]
insert a[15:15] b[15:16]
Inserted: '\xd0'
 equal a[15:45] b[16:46]
insert a[45:45] b[46:47]
Inserted: '\xd0'
 equal a[45:85] b[47:87]
>>> expected[14:17]
'\x82\xd0\xb5'
>>> given[14:18]
'\x82\xd0\xd0\xb5'
>>> expected[44:47]
'\xbd\xd0\xbe'
>>> given[45:49]
'\xbd\xd0\xd0\xbe'
>>> given = '\xd0\xaf \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe \xd0, \xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7 \xd0\xb2\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbc\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9'
>>> expected = 'Я не против первого, но без второго мне веселей' # requires UTF-8 terminal
>>> for opcode in difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=expected, b=given).get_opcodes():
...     print "%6s a[%d:%d] b[%d:%d]" % opcode
...     if opcode[0] == 'insert': print 'Inserted:', repr(given[opcode[3]:opcode[4]])
... 
 equal a[0:35] b[0:35]
insert a[35:35] b[35:37]
Inserted: ' \xd0'
 equal a[35:85] b[37:87]
>>> expected[34:38]
'\xbe, \xd0'
>>> given[34:40]
'\xbe \xd0, \xd0'
```

In the title, two extra `\xd0` bytes were inserted where there already was a `\xd0` byte. In the description, a *space* and `\xd0` was inserted before a comma, space, `\xd0` sequence.

This is a failure of your terminal, not Python.  *Why* this happens, is not clear however.

Comment: Now I get the same error when invoking `decode(sys.stdin.encoding)`. By the way it's `UTF-8`. I don't know why by it still doesn't happen all the time...

Comment: How certain are you that it is the `raw_input()` data that is triggering the traceback? Have you tried encoding all strings in your dictionary by other means and verified what byte strings are not UTF-8?

Comment: I also qualified using `sys.stdin.encoding` with *If correctly configured*. What console is this? Are you using Windows or something else?

Comment: I use Ubuntu. About your previous question about how I know that inputted data triggers exception - because when I do decoding in the same line with input then I get this line in traceback. Other values in dictionary are just ascii or int numbers.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: Hrm, Ubuntu terminals usually have sane settings. You used the word 'console' however, which usually implies either the Windows CMD window or an IDE console, and the latter are prone to getting things like encodings wrong sometimes.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: when the encoding fails, what is the `repr()` of the data? What is `sys.stdin.encoding` set to, and what is the text you entered?

Comment: `sys.stding.encoding` is `UTF-8` and text I've entered for `description` now is `я не против первого, но без второго мне веселей`. I was able to reproduce the exception only after several inputs. What do you mean by `repr()` - the dictionary content?

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: the content of the string returned when decoding fails. `item['title'] = raw_input('Title: ')`, `try: item['title'] = item['title'].decode(sys.stdin.encoding)`, `except UnicodeDecodeError: print repr(item['title'])`, so we can diagnose what exactly was input to throw this exception. The fact that it is intermittent is interesting, I don't know yet what is added to the string to make the decoding fail.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: Interesting, the actual input has extra `\xd0` bytes. The title has those at positions 16 and and 47. Your terminal is botching UTF-8 input somewhere.

Comment: wow... so it really breaks my utf strings. Now I need to figure out what to do with that, thank you.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: it's as if bytes are being retransmitted. The description corruption is especially weird. This is not something that can easily be fixed after the fact.

Comment: Everything works fine on another machine with the same Ubuntu version... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to have been of help, anyway, then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use simple **raw_input()** you give only bytes:

```
>>> raw_input('Input: ')
Input: фыв
'\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2'
```

Use **unicode()** to convert input string to unicode

```
>>> unicode(raw_input('Input: '), encoding='utf-8')
Input: фыв
u'\u0444\u044b\u0432'
```

and then try work with json

Comment: That's what the `encoding` parameter to `json.dumps()` *does*.

Comment: Moreover, this will **not** solve the issue with the data not being encoding in UTF-8 in the first place. Note that from the traceback you can see that `json.dumps()` is already using UTF-8 to decode a byte string, **and this fails**.